# Is there a quick way to disable a keyboard temporarily while cleaning it without unplugging it?

Tags: keyboard

For example if you are cleaning a keyboard. You want to mash the keys. For a while, then have it work again. Mouse based click on off could work. Unplugging is a pain.

I should add that I am on Ubuntu but the other answers are still useful.

Comment: Why not just shut it down?

Comment: @spikey_richie yes unplug etc. I want to get in the habit of doing this everyday though.

Comment: If you are cleaning with a liquid, do not spray the keyboard.  Spray the cloth and make sure its not dripping.  Even a small amount of liquid getting inside can potentially cause issues.  Better safe, than sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Windows 10 or Windows 11 there is currently no feature to temporary disable the keyboard/keys with one button click from the settings sadly, but you can temporarily:

1. Remove Device (with Windows Settings)
   `Right-Click Windows Logo -> Settings -> Bluetooth and Devices -> Devices -> Input`
   Click the three dots and `Remove Device` on the entry of your Keyboard
   (Name for example "wired keyboard" with cherry wired keyboard).
2. Do the cleaning
3. "Add" Device (Rescan Devices with Device Manager)
   `Right-Click Windows Logo -> Device Manager`
   Click the Button `Scan for hardware changes` in the Top Menu.
   It should automatically appear again.

Be aware that settings that are not stored on the Keyboard could be lost or not "mapped" to the Keyboard anymore.

Yes, Device Manager can disable the keyboard.
But in my case with **one** connected keyboard Device Manager shows **five** identical "HID-Keyboard" entries and disabling them or finding the right takes more time in my case...

Yes, there is third-party software that is more easy to use but can never be faster/quicker than onboard options (find trustworhy software, download/install, get along with ui)

Yes, there are other reasons users want to do this and microsoft should know/enable it:
[Microsoft Community Question: How do I disable my laptop built-in keyboard?](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-do-i-disable-my-laptop-built-in-keyboard/8ab09573-7564-4345-85ee-6fe194da235c)

Answer (score 2):

In terms of Windows, you could theorectically go into device manager and uninstall the keyboard. Then do the cleaning, then right click device manager and select "scan for hardware changes" which should reinstall the keyboard driver.

I just tested on my workstation and it worked without an issue. You may have other results, but if it's Windows 10, it is probably safe.

I should note that my keyboard is a Microsoft wired keyboard, and the special buttons for volume and calculator all worked after doing this.

Comment: Why not just disable the keyboard in DM?

Answer (score 2):

For macOS, get [KeyboardCleanTool](https://folivora.ai/keyboardcleantool) (freeware)

Does what it says on the tin.
Mouse still works, so you can click to deactivate afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest thing is to exit to the lock screen <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> on Windows.  You are unlikely to enter the password or pin to log in accidentally.  Equally you won't be pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> easily.